# Fast python front list extending

Tags: python, performance, list, profiling, concatenation

What is the fastest way to extend the front of an array in python? Lets say I've got 2 arrays:
a and b. I want to make the fastest way of a = b+a (b should not change).

My small benchamarks:

test 1:

```
a,b = [],[]
for i in range(0,100000):
    a.append(i)
    b.append(i)

def f(a,b):
    for i in range(0,100):
        a=a+b

import cProfile
cProfile.run('f(a,b)')
```

time: ~12 s

test 2:

```
a,b = [],[]
for i in range(0,100000):
    a.append(i)
    b.append(i)

def f(a,b):
    for i in range(0,100):
        a[0:0] = b

import cProfile
cProfile.run('f(a,b)')
```

time: ~1.5s

test3:

```
a,b = [],[]
for i in range(0,100000):
    a.append(i)
    b.append(i)

lenb = len(b)
def f(a,b):
    for i in range(0,100):
        b.extend(a)
        # do something with b
        b = b[:lenb]

import cProfile
cProfile.run('f(a,b)')
```

time: ~0.4s

But i think It should be faster, because lists concatenation should be made as change of few underlying pointers.
And the following code is the fastest one, but changes b, not a (SO IT IS NOT GOOD FOR OUR PURPOSE):
test "WRONG":

```
a,b = [],[]
for i in range(0,100000):
    a.append(i)
    b.append(i)

def f(a,b):
    for i in range(0,100):
        b.extend(a)

import cProfile
cProfile.run('f(a,b)')
```

time: ~0.13s

So theoretically there should be a way to extend front of a in time of test "WRONG".

Comment: `from collections import deque`

Comment: Note, what you have are lists, not arrays.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The absolute fastest way would be to use a [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.deque) which is optimised for exactly this use, and has methods called `.appendleft` and `.extendleft` to make the code nice and readable - `appendleft` does exactly what it says on the tin (ie, it appends to the left of the deque), and `extendleft` does the equivalent of:

```
def extendleft(self, other)
    for item in other:
        self.appendleft(c)
```

so, `a = b+a` would be spelled:

```
a.extendleft(reversed(b))
```

Comment: You want to use `a.extendleft(reversed(b))` because `extendleft` consumes the given iterable from its head (just like a snake eating a mouse).